# Why was xpath rules removed from JavaScript plugin?

Tags: sonarqube

I was surprised to find out that the xpath custom rule was removed from the JavaScript plugin.
as you can see in:
http://jira.sonarsource.com/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10933&version=11669
and
http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-314

- why is that?
- is the only way to write custom rule is by writing a Java plugin?
- we are relying heavily on custom rules in other languages (C#, C++), should we expect those to be removed also?
- why isn't Sonar kept backward compatible?

Thanks,
Roy.

Comment: Is a query selector rule supported?

Comment: Not sure I understand, what are the query selector rules? - what I meant was the xpath template rule, which you can use as a template for creating custom rules by writing xpath queries on the abstract syntax tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in newer versions of the Java and JavaScript plugins custom rules do need to be written in Java. The move has been made for long-term stability. The underlying structures that XPath rules were dependent on were subject to change from version to version - invalidating your XPath rules, perhaps without you noticing.

The API's on which custom-rules-in-Java are based should be much more stable from version to version.

I would anticipate C/C++ rules needing to be moved to Java at some point, but it will probably be a while. As for C#, since the analyzer is now written *in* C#, I doubt you'll ever need to write custom rules in Java. :-)

To your final point, an effort is made to keep things stable, but nothing can remain backward compatible forever. Sometimes, for the sake of being able to move forward, old branches have to be cut, and that is the case with the XPath rule implementations.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.